# PostgreSQL get last value in a comma separated list of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a PostgreSQL table I have a column which has values like

```
AX,B,C
A,BD
X,Y
J,K,L,M,N
```

In short , it will have a few comma separated strings in the column for each record. I wanted to get the last one in each record. I ended up with this.

```
select id, reverse(substr(reverse(mycolumn),1,position(',' in reverse(mycolumn)))) from mytable order by id ;
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: So you're creating your own comma-separated data structure inside PostgreSQL which is specifically designed for creating and storing data structures. Why?

Comment: Fix your schema now, before it's too late. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/postgresql-list-of-integers-separated-by-comma-or-integer-array-for-performance and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why

Comment: @Craig Ringer - Thanks for the pointers. The column actually holds just one attribute - an institute name - which can have commas in between. And the last part of the name has some relevance, which is why I wanted to extract that. I don't think it is necessary to separate that into a separate column in the same table or in another table.

Comment: @Jayadevan Ok, that's less crazy than the description made it sound ;-) and there's a time to give up on normalization (e.g. the nightmare that is residential / postal addressing). I was concerned you might be doing one of those comma-separated-array-in-a-text-field things I'm seeing every ... person ... and their dog do lately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `regexp_replace`:

```
select id, regexp_replace(mycolumn, '.*,', '')
from mytable
order by id;
```

Comment: It is probably not a general solution as `.*` will likely miss some chars. I like `reverse(split_part(reverse(myColumn), ',', 1))` better.

Answer (score 12):

I would do it this way:

```
select reverse(split_part(reverse(myColumn), ',', 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, better than mine. Let us see if there are shorter ones.

Comment: Wrap the result with another reverse: select reverse(reverse(split_part(reverse(myColumn), ',', 1)))

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easier way?

With your current data, Gordon's answer works best imo. Other options would be a regex (messy), or converting the column to a text[] array e.g. `('{' || col || '}')::text[]` or variations thereof.

If you were using a text[] array instead of plain text for your column, you'd want to use array functions directly:

```
select col[array_length(col, 1)]
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Example with dummy data:

```
 with bar as (
 select '{a,b,c}'::text[] as foo
 )
 select foo[array_length(foo, 1)] from bar;
```

You could, of course, also create a `parse_csv()` function or `get_last_csv_value()` function to avoid writing the above.